# Trigger model method on creation or field change

Tags: python, django

Assume, that I have this model in django:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    x = models.FloatField(null=True)
    y = models.FloatField(null=True)
    z = models.FloatField(null=True)
    v = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def get_z(self):
        z = x / y
        self.z = z
        self.save()

    def get_v(self):
        v = z * x
        self.v = v
        self.save()
```

When I create an object with admin panel then I provide only name, number, x and y fields. I need to z and v field calculate automatically on object creation or whenever any of fields changes they value. For now it's working via making:

```
 z_value = property(get_z)
```

and putting z_value in list_display in admin panel, then when I go there, values are saved.

Comment: Why have this redundancy at all? Why not make z and v properties?

Comment: You mean @property decorator? I can refactor this, but I think it not solves my problem?

Comment: Why don't you override the `save` method and do the calculations there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the safe method like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    ...
    x = models.FloatField(null=True)
    y = models.FloatField(null=True)
    z = models.FloatField(null=True)
    v = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.z = self.x / self.y
        self.v = self.z * self.x
        super(Example, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The reasons to populate fields during save is that it will make it much easier to query. But there are also downsides. For example, you have to make sure to never use `update()` on these fields. The save method won't be be called on update!

So it might be better to write a normalised model like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    ...
    x = models.FloatField(null=True)
    y = models.FloatField(null=True)

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.x / self.y

    @property
    def v(self):
        return self.z * self.x
```

To do anything with z and v in a queryset you have to annotate fields. Something like this:

```
Example.objects.annotate(z=Sum(F('x') / F('y'))).annotate(v=Sum(F('z') * F('x')))
```

Comment: Ok, now I know how to do that. I like the first example, but will it work when I just do: ` obj = Example.object.get(name='ex')       obj.name = 'new_value'      obj.save()`  ?

Comment: Yes, both models return identical values. Of course you can't set `z` or `v` in both cases. In the first example it will be ignored, in the second there is no db field to store that data at all.

Comment: I would say the second is 'better' from a purist point of view. But if you have a good understanding of normalised and denormalised databases, you could argue the first fits better with your project requirements.